# meteor deployment - how to create source maps?

Tags: meteor, deployment, source-maps

Using meteor, Is there a way to create source maps in the deploy process?

The purpose is to upload the source maps to a js error tracker service (atatus.com) which supports them, to have more helpful error messages. Right now the only source maps I found in the .meteor dir are of the development env.

Comment: can you accept my answer please, or provide feedback?

Answer (score 5):

I think you can do this by switching out the standard minifier package that comes with meteor for zodern:standard-minifier-js.  See instructions at  https://github.com/zodern/minify-js-sourcemaps

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but the answer is no, you cannot generate source maps in the deploy process. Meteor Development Group has not made sourcemaps available as a feature for deployments.

For reference, the relevant Meteor github issue requesting this feature is: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4384

Comment: whoever voted me down, please explain how I can improve this answer

Comment: I too gets annoyed when people down vote for an unknown reason. Anyway, I'm not the down voter but you could probably elaborate on why the answer is no.

Comment: it's "no" because you can't; the framework doesn't support it.